# Why is this jQuery .find() not selecting ALL the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm not sure why jquery isn't selecting all the elements with an id starting with "widhet_slot" or with the class "widget slot".

```
<section class="header-box widget_slot" id="widget_slot_header"></section>
<section class="wall-of-counters">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_1"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_2"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_3"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_4"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_5"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_6"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_7"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_8"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_9"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_10"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_11"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_12"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_13"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_14"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_15"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_16"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_17"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_18"></span>
        <span class="cell widget_slot" id="widget_slot_19"></span>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="footer-box widget_slot" id="widget_slot_footer"></section>
```

I'm loading this selection via ajax, and sending it to jquery. I'm logging the output:

```
$.get "#{durl}/layouts/#{lname}/#{version}/html", (data) ->
    console.log data
    console.log $ data
    console.log $(data).find '[id^=widget_slot]'
    console.log $(data).find '.widget_slot'
```

The outputs are:

[image: the results]

**The Problem**

As you can see, the header and footer are not selected by `"[id^=widget_slot]"` while nothing is selected by `'.widget_slot'`

Is this to be expected? I've also tried `"*[id^=widget_slot]"` with the same result.

**EDIT:**

I updated the logging for the class part. I made a mistake, though in correcting it, bizarrely, I still don't get the output I expected.

Comment: Don't see element with class `.widget_slot`. To get header and footer, use `$(data).filter('[id^=widget_slot]');`

Comment: @DanielCheung Does it??? The [doc](https://api.jquery.com/find/) say _Get the descendant**s** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element._

Comment: @DanielCheung: no it wont. unless id selector is used or one element exists for query

Comment: I've voted to close this as **a simple typographical error**. The `id` selector is prefixed with a `#`. The `.` prefix selects on the element's `class`. See [jQuery's Selectors documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Sorry, just checked, I lied :(

Comment: `find()` excludes parent elements, so to retrieve the header and footer you need to use `filter()` and then `add()` the results of filter/find together. Ugly. A better solution would be to add a single parent element around the entire response. Then `find()` alone will work for you.

Comment: Sorry, the class one was a mistake. I was using two servers, and I forgot to restart (or even read the output of) the source of the HTML-serving one. The ID one is my actual question here. Let me change the question to remove the class out.

Comment: `$('<div/>', {html: data}).find '[id^=widget_slot]'`  See [Rory's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338283/why-is-this-jquery-find-not-selecting-all-the-elements#comment-58383905)

Comment: Try "[id*=...] instead of "[id^=...]

Comment: @A.Wolff, Either you or Rory should post the answer and close it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't know that (nor found it obvious from the wording in the docs). However, you are completely right. I don't want to have to combine `find/filter` so I'll just add a wrapper `section` around it. Thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, that works too. Actually I lean more to your answer, as it doesn't make me have to modify the HTML already written.